# Reading html from local html file with HTMLUNIT

Tags: java, web, web-crawler, htmlunit

I am trying to load a local html file which I have downloaded. Does anybody know how to do this? I am currently getting statuscode[404].

this is how I am doing it

```
HtmlPage htmlPage=webClient.getPage("file:\\\\Users\\njd202\\Desktop\\zipmeupbich\\springbootmongodb\\src\\main\\resources\\downloadedfiles\\Cuban2.html") ;
```

Comment: Recheck if path exists. Replace '\\' by '/'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have done a short test here and it works fine for me.

```
webClient.getPage("file:\\\\C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\htmlunit\\test.html"
```

Please check if you are

- using the latest HtmlUnit version
- using the right path
- start with a file with really simple html content (no external links/references)